# Prove that $_n$ is generated by the two permutations (1 2), (1 2 3 ... n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I've to prove that <sub>*n*</sub> is generated by the two permutations (1 2), (1 2 3 ... *n*).

I've already proved that the symmetric group can generated by the following transpositions

(1 2) (2 3) (3 4), ..., (*n* − 1 n)

in a previous exercise.

So I think I've to prove that those two elements are able to generate all elements of the form (m,m+1) with $m = 1, \ldots n-1$

Comment: Good idea. I'd look at $c^{-1} (12) c$ where $c$ is the long cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$(12)(123 \dots n)=(13)$$ $$(13)(123 \dots n)=(14)$$ $$(14)(123 \dots n)=(15)$$ $$\vdots$$ $$(1 \text{ n -1})(123 \dots n)=(1 \text{ n})$$

Next we do, $$(12)(13)(12)^{-1}=(23)$$ $$(13)(14)(13)^{-1}=(34)$$ $$\vdots$$ $$(1\text{ n-1} )(1\text{ n} ){(1 \text{ n-1} )}^{-1}=(\text{n-1} \text{ n})$$